# Make Gridview read ConnectionString from Session?

Tags: asp.net, session, gridview, connection-string

**How can get my `SQLDataSource` to read the `ConnectionString` from a session variable?**

I know I can do it in code, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uxDS.ConnectionString = Session["con"].ToString();
}
```

But what I really want is something like this?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="uxDS" ... ConnectionString='<% Session["con"] %>' />
```

I could have sworn I saw it done somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: This sure makes me think that what you really need is a more robust data access layer that understands about multi-tenancy coupled with an ObjectDataSource.  This would help you localize the code that deals with the multi-tenancy aspects in one place, helping to prevent errors and cascading edits when you need to change how it works.  I suppose there are some simple scenarios where this makes sense, but I'm skeptical.

Comment: I'm doing this because I hate multiple `web.config` files so I have : `Session_Start(...){ if(HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName == "..."){ Session["con"] = "..." } }`

Comment: Have you considered using Web.Config transformations with different publishing targets for each machine?  Seems a lot cleaner.  In any event, my comment was more directed toward scattering the connection string assignment logic throughout your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="uxDS" ... ConnectionString='<%# Session["con"] %>' />
```

Comment: It tells me that `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.` even though binding with the exact same string in the code-behind works correctly.